# file sharing site (legal) php script

Tags: php, web, cloud

OK i am setting a family file sharing site.I want to copy files from set destinations (E.G "My Documents").I want to know if i can use php code to take the files from the computer and store them on the web server i have seen:

```
file_put_contents( 'E:\somefile.txt', $data);
```

Also

```
copy('test.jpg, 'Iomega_HDD/test2.jpg')
```

And

```
copy('test.jpg, '/Volumes/Iomega_HDD/test2.jpg')
```

But being new to php i want to know how i would implement it fully.

Comment: Only if the local folder is shared with your webserver, or they are uploaded through a web form

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, your best bet would be to create a web form with an upload facility on it, that anyone in your family could access and upload files they wanted to share to the server, these files could then be listed for group access.

You might be better off serving the files directly from your local machine however, it depends if the files are coming from multiple locations (i.e. if you want all members of your family to contribute.)

Honestly, unless you are doing this for the learning though, dropbox has this problem solved.

Comment: so any ideas on how i cando this ?

Comment: So, with regard to my comments, what is your situation? Do you want to share files from one computer to many, or do lots of files from lots of computers want to be uploaded to the server? I will edit my answer with some basic file upload web form code you could use to make a web page that anyone could transfer files onto the server